# Allowing select and input checkboxes to be editable

Tags: checkbox, tinymce, html-select, tinymce-4

An HTML template that I'm working on has a variety of HTML select and checkbox elements contained within it.

Eg.

```
<select>
   <option></option>
   <option>No</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" />
```

I've found that these elements do not appear to be editable from within the WYSIWYG editor.

I would like a user to be able to toggle the checkboxes and select options from within these elements from within the WYSIWYG editor.

So the HTML could be turned into something like this:

```
<select>
   <option></option>
   <option selected>No</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

Has anyone been able to acheive this in TinyMCE 4?

Is there a plugin that may help that I haven't found? Are there techincal challenges to achieving this as a plugin?

Thanks for any help/advice!

**Update:**

I've discovered the inability to change these element within the editor is actually a [reported bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416766) with Firefox since 2008! In other browsers you are able to change the values of these elements - however as no changes are made to the HTML - their state is not saved.

Perhaps a plugin to record the state of these elements into the HTML source just prior to saving, would fulfil my requirement?